# create a virtual directory for a website programmatically- web application

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, virtual-directory

I would like to know if it possible to create a virtual directory in C# directly to a site instead of creating a web application and then linking a virtual directory to that. I am using iis 7. thanks ! 
Src:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx

Comment: This should be moved to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in PowerShell.

[From Learn IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/)

```
PS IIS:\> New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\DemoVirtualDir1' -type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath c:\test\virtualDirectory1
```

Comment: Did you read the answer? I provided a PowerShell line that will do it. If you want it in a different language, then ask for it specifically. I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I would like to have it in C#

Comment: Then this belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in c#. worked for me.

```
using (ServerManager srv = new ServerManager())
{
    var site = srv.Sites.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == siteName);
    var app = site.Applications.Add("/SubDirecory1/SubDirectory2", acbphysicalPath.Text +  @"\SubDirectory1\SubDirectory2");
    app.ApplicationPoolName = txtAppPool.Text;
    srv.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft.Web.Administration you can do:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Application app = iisManager.Sites[“NewSite”].Applications[“/Sales”];
app.VirtualDirectories.Add(“/VDir”, “d:\\MyVDir”);
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

Read more on it here:

- https://johnlnelson.com/2014/06/15/the-microsoft-web-administration-namespace/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2006/04/17/microsoft-web-administration-in-iis-7/